# When are static members evaluated in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

I'm trying to load the api url from my .env file (I'm using the flutter_dotenv package) and store it on a static member `apiUrl` of an abstract class named `Constants`.

The problem is that `apiUrl` gets evaluated before I can load the environment variables from my `main` function, which throws the error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'NotInitializedError'
```

The `main` function

```
void main() async {

  await dotenv.load();

  runApp(const App());
}
```

The `Constants` class

```
abstract class Constants {
  static final String apiUrl = dotenv.get('API_URL');
  // other stuff
}
```

Is there a way to solve this? Thanks in advance for any responses

Comment: Static variables are evaluated at the point of first access of the value. So they are by default lazy evaluated. So there must be something which tries to use `apiUrl` before trying to load (if the error actually comes from `dotenv.get('API_URL')`)